# Solr - Remove specific punctuation marks

Tags: solr, solrj

I am working with apache-solr-3.6.0 on windows machine. I would like to remove all punctuation marks before indexing except the colon and the full-stop.

I tried:

```
<fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[\p{Punct}&&[^\.^\:]]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

But it didn't work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following pattern filter instead of yours.

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9.:])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working as I am dealing with arabic characters.

Comment: I tried it with the english characters and it worked for me.I don't know why it is not working with arabic characters.

Comment: Arabic couldn't be treated as a-z and so on in regex.

Comment: Then you should find a way to distinguish arabic letter using regex. There are some suggestions such as using unicode characters in regex. Search on the google.Hope you can find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I 'll give a try.

Comment: The regex for matching Arabic characters is: `[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it along with other regex. But still it could find punctuation marks. 
Although the parsed query didnt contain the punctuation mark, 

`<str name="rawquerystring">"{"</str>
<str name="querystring">"{"</str>
<str name="parsedquery">text:</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">text:</str>
`
 but still the numfound gives 1 

`<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">`

and the highlight shows the result of punctuation mark 
` <em>{</em>`
The steps I did: 
1- editing the schema 
2- restart the server 
3-delete the file 
4-index the file